# How to increase quick action modal width and height in Lightning by styling in latest release?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am not able to override the parent modal generated by quick action.

Comment: An example which we could try? and maybe some screenshots to avoid any confusion?

Comment: Please read [ask], it will help you write better questions, which will enable the community to help you

Answer (score 6):

You can't override the modal created by the quick action. That's one of the key points of Locker Service. The height is adjustable by editing the quick action, but the width is fixed. This is intentional so that the quick action will fit on all types of devices, one of the design goals of Lightning.